# Site Rules - Are subjective (non open ended) questions allowed if the intent is clearly to quantify the results by votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, asking-questions, stack-exchange

For example, say I was to ask something like "Amongst Stack Exchange Members, which of the Two Following Ways is Most Preferred for Bracketing..."

Then I left two answers like:

Answer 1) Like This:

```
public void aFunc(){
    //code here
}
```

... Then I post another answer ...

Answer 2) Like This:

```
public void aFunc()
{
    //code here
}
```

Is this kind of thing allowed? I'm not sure I completely understand the rules here but it wouldn't be open ended and could actually provide objective information...

Amusingly, the best way to find out whether or not the community as a whole would accept this is probably through either yes or no votes on answers

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: As above, I thought not but would someone mind explaining what's wrong with this?

Comment: Um, everything? :) Subjective questions are discouraged, why should subjective polls be exempted?

Comment: How is "a shit ton of subjective opinions about something" objective data? we have no way to really know who votes, so it's hard to pull data... you can say "well at least x people, with the skill ranging from Jon Skeet to someone who barely knows half of a programming language (sorry php), think this is better than this"....

Comment: So where or how would you gather this kind of information? Say for example you wanted this information as part of a project developing a new IDE aimed at SE users. 
By the way this is a completely hypothetical example and probably not the best one.

Comment: Good question on WHERE... but the answer is surely NOT "anywhere on the stack exchange network"

Comment: Also this entire site is to some extent subjective, an answer with the most votes still gets that way based on opinion. An answer with the least votes could still be the most suitable answer

Comment: People vote based on opinion and experience and the current location of their keys etc. *Posts* should be based on facts, not opinions.

Comment: So if the above question was rephrased to state "what do people use most...?" and the answers were changed to fit. Is this still too subjective?

Comment: That is still opinion based. How do you quantify "people" and "use most" without opinionated bias? Stack Overflow is about useful solutions to common programming problems for programmers everywhere. You cannot objectively quantify which would be used more or for what reasons, because it would be based on opinion. Questions should ask for facts that can be proved using other facts.

Comment: @Joekomino it is definitely commendable that you're trying to build a good tool for devs.... unfortunately, that kind of question, no matter how you phrase it, will be closed as they are off-topic. Doesn't mean they are BAD questions. Just means that, for the format Stack Overflow chose for itself, they don't work.... you'll need to hit another website with these. Which, I have no clue to be honest

Comment: http://www.slant.co/ got tossed around quite a bit a while back when people would wonder where to go with questions like these. Never looked at it for more than three minutes myself, but it's explicitly designed _for_ polling as far as I know. /cc @Patrice

Comment: @JoshCaswell thank you for that. I wasn't even AWARE of that website :P

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I think I'm misrepresenting myself here. Unfortunately, I feel like I intuitively know what I am trying to say but I am having a hard time formalising it. (your answer may not change but I'll have another stretch)... If (in some way) a question was posted in the above FORMAT (the poll style format is probably an important part) - with the sole purpose of QUANTIFYING opinion bias -  for the purpose (in full or part) of creating (or otherwise altering) programmatic solutions... is this in ANY possible way suitable? - I'm still struggling to word this

Comment: @Joekomino No, it's not.  SO is a question and answer site for specific practical programming problems, not a survey/poll site.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it can be made possible withoutn the poll format

Comment: On a similar note, is this actually a bad or subjective question? It's been down voted a bunch. Where should I ask these kinds of questions? I was told by another user to ask them here (on Meta as oppsed to SO) :s makes sense to me to clarify this kind of thing

Comment: "No polling" is a pretty core aspect of SE, @Joekomino, and it does come up a fair bit. One of the most common reason downvotes are cast on Meta is for lack of research into past discussions (and the help center) -- because endlessly rehashing the same topic isn't particularly fun or useful. Personally, I don't think there's much wrong with your question, but everyone's allowed their voting opinion.

Comment: As an infrequent user/ SO Noob, even I see a tonne of duplicate and "bad" questions from other users so I get where you're coming from. That said... as an SO noob, This entire site looks like one giant polling system, so the thought of searching questions about polls didn't even cross my mind. perhaps this site should add a separate search algorithm for newcomers that shows them SITE BASED noob questions first. Like a priority section that disappears after so many hours of use or something. I bet some great programmers join this and still make errors regarding the site policies

Comment: Anyway, should I be deleting this post? What's the drill in this situation? I personally think it MIGHT just prevent the question being asked by quite so many people in the future but it certainly is getting a lot of down votes. what's the best way to proceed here?

Comment: Create a poll and post it to twitter/linkedin/whatever.

Comment: Downvotes on meta signal agreement or disagreement / approval or disapproval. On meta downvoted questions don't need to be deleted, it just means that a lot of user disagreed with your sentiment. Votes are free on meta and you don't gain / lose any rep from them, so don't take it too seriously.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, just wondering if it'll add to a "clogging" of the site or is likely to benefit someone. Some people on here seem to take things way too seriously and I'm still trying to gauge what the standards are here.

Comment: @Joe Meta doesn't have a problem with too many posts as of yet. When the day comes that meta overtakes main for questions posted in a day, then  I would be worried about it. Otherwise, don't worry.

Comment: @Joekomino negative votes is not a reason to  delete post on META as otherwise there would be daily stream of identical question and no way to find things that are already discussed to be "bad idea for SO/META".

Comment: I think on questions like this, down votes can also be interpreted as meaning "no" or "I think this is a bad idea". So rather than a bunch of comments or answers that just say 'No', they down vote the question.

Comment: *perhaps this site should add a separate search algorithm for newcomers that shows them SITE BASED noob questions first.* - There have been similar feature requests for things like quizzes on site policies that new users would have to pass first but they always get shot down. You are right though that being a good programmer and understanding the site rules are two separate things. Even people who have been here for a while will get tripped up on the conventions for new privileges (ex. review queues).

Comment: I suppose the quiz idea might put people off if they are pushed for time when signing up but it seems that not doing this (or finding another solution) wastes everybody's time - including the posters - and reduces the quality of the posts. Why do they always end up being shot down?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [help center on what you shouldn't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> [Questions where] every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

and

> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people
>   feel like I do.”

Your question is basically a poll.  It isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: Further reading: [The fourth place: polling, recommendations, and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383) What happened shortly thereafter: [Adding discipline to programmers.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65437) And the aftermath: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/159251)

Comment: I would upvote that ^^^ But I [ran out of comment votes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267503/menu-to-show-daily-progress-towards-vote-flag-limits)